# run multiple command from cmd using c#

Tags: c#, cmd, arguments

Im trying to run both of arg1 and arg2 in the cmd. But I get syntax error, I do not where is the erorr. I Also tried to use space rather than & but it also did not work. I might mention from cmd works perfectly fine as in the photo. from c# if I run arg1 alone it works fine but when I want to run both I get the error.

```
if (GUILayout.Button("Load File"))
    {
     
        string pathRenamed = myPath.Replace(@"\", "/");
        pathRenamed = pathRenamed.Remove(pathRenamed.Length - 1);
         Debug.Log("Ausgewählter Pfad:" + pathRenamed);

        string fileName; //get file name
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathRenamed);

        string exteName;// get file name without Extension
        exteName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathRenamed);

        int index = pathRenamed.LastIndexOf("/"); // remove file name from pathrenamed and get only the directory 
        if (index > 0)
            pathRenamed = pathRenamed.Substring(0, index);
        
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
         p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = pathRenamed;
       String exePath;
        exePath = UnityEngine.Application.dataPath + "/IfcConvert.exe";
       
        

        string arg1;
        string arg2;
        arg1 = "/k " + "\"" + "\"" + exePath + "\"" + "\" " + fileName + " " + exteName + ".obj --use-element-guids ";
        arg2 =  "\"" + "\"" + exePath + "\"" + "\" " + fileName + " " + exteName + ".xml --use-element-guids ";

        p.StartInfo.Arguments = $@"{arg1} & {arg2}";
        Debug.Log($"{arg1} & {arg2}");
```

Comment: Please read my comments below the question [How to find a word in CMD Command Output C# Console App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67322251/) It makes never sense to use the C# classes `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` to start `cmd.exe` using in background `CreateProcess` and `STARTUPINFO` for execution of one or more executables by `cmd.exe` which uses also `CreatePrcoess` and `STARTUPINFO` for each executable to run. Why do you not use the C# classes `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` to run one executable after the other without using `cmd.exe` at all making C# code much easier?

Comment: I am surprised it works with just `arg1` - you seem to have some issues with your quotes not being separated by spaces as you build your command string. Perhaps try using string interpolation instead.

Comment: FYI, you can use `Path.GetDirectoryName(pathRenamed)` to get the directory path without the filename

Comment: What specific error are you getting?

Comment: @rufus L 
The syntax for the file name, directory name, or volume label is incorrect.

Comment: My command, which works in the cmd looks like this, the directory, test.ifc, test are variables:

"C:/Users/salim/OneDrive/Desktop/New Unity Project (1)/Assets/IfcConvert.exe" test.ifc test.obj --use-element-guids & "C:/Users/salim/OneDrive/Desktop/New Unity Project (1)/Assets/IfcConvert.exe" test.ifc test.xml --use-element-guids

Comment: @salimBekandi If you would have read the help of Windows command processor as suggested in my first comment (deleted now) by opening a command prompt window and running `cmd /?`, you would have most likely solved the problem by yourself. You have to  enclose the __entire command line__ after option `/k` additionally in `"` or the ampersand is escaped with `^` to get it first interpreted as literal character on `cmd.exe` processing the arguments list and later as conditional command operator on processing the command line before finally executing it.

Comment: Easier would be using in C# code the classes `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` to run first `C:\Users\salim\OneDrive\Desktop\New Unity Project (1)\Assets\IfcConvert.exe` with its arguments and use next once more `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` to run once more the same executable in same working directory (not defined by your code, can be any of the thousands of directories on a Windows machine) with the different arguments list.

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). The directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as used by you for some unknown reason. File/folder names with `/` just work because of Windows file management replaces all `/` in a file/folder name by ``\`` before passing the string to the file system as described by the referenced Microsoft documentation. You should really write the C# code correct and not intentionally with syntax mistakes which Windows has to correct on execution.